# i'm trying to create a twitch chrome extention but my code is for the old twitch api

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need help,
I create a chrome extention thanks to this website : https://www.grafikart.fr/tutoriels/extension-chrome-firefox-twitch-900
the only problem is that it works with the old twitch api and i don't know how to use the new one so there is my main.js :

```
setInterval(function(){
    checkstream()

}, 5000)
function checkstream() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("GET", "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/kalevis_?client_id=000000000000000000000000000000", true)
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
        if(data["stream"] == null){
                $("#activity").html("Kalevis_ ne stream pas ")
            }else{
                $("#activity").html("Kalevis_ est en train de stream")
                var notif = new Notification('kalevis_',{
                    'icon' : 'img/icon.png',
                    'body' : 'kalevis_ est en live'
                })
            }
        }else{
            $("#activity").html("Error")
        }
       };
       xhr.send();

}
```

and my html page :

```
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                background-image:url(https://forums-images.oneplus.net/attachments/547/547028-7aac0a57f8e75169e7c3ca3500d7987e.jpg);
            }
            h4 {
                color: blanchedalmond;
            }
            .img {
                border: 5px solid white !important;
                box-shadow: 0 5px 24px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 5px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.22) !important;
                border-radius:5rem
            }
            .btn {
                -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
                -moz-border-radius: 3px;
                border-radius: 3px;
            }
            h4 {
                font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif !important;
            }



        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <center>
            <h4 style="font-size: 3em !important;margin-bottom:0px;padding-left:30px;padding-right: 30px;">kalevis_</h4>
            <img class="img" src="img/icon.png" width="70px" height="70px" alt="">
            <h4 id="activity">Kalevis_</h4>
            <p id="debug"></p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="twitch">twitch</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="discord">discord</button>
        </center>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/click.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
```

the problem is that it isn't compatible with the new twitch api so it doesn't show any output
can someone help me to convert it to the new version of the twitch api

Answer (score 0):

that's ok i find a solution i simply use JQuery so my new working main.js is :

```
var api = 'helix';
var client_id = 'awn5pjjdxpb0mieqeb96d8cwr682nj';
var user = '45885376'; //id de Kalevis : 45885376
var timeToCheckLive = '120000';
var timeToResetNotifs = '10800000';





checkStream(user, client_id, api);

var check = setInterval(function(){
    checkStream(user, client_id, api);

}, timeToCheckLive );


function checkStream(user, client_id, api){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            beforeSend: function(request) {
              request.setRequestHeader("Client-Id", client_id);
            },
            url: "https://api.twitch.tv/"+api+"/streams?user_id="+user,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                var data = response.data[0]; 
                if(typeof data == "undefined"){
                    //stream is offline
                }else{
                    var gameId = data["game_id"];
                    var liveTitle = data["title"];
                    var liveViewersCount = data["viewer_count"];
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        beforeSend: function(request) {
                          request.setRequestHeader("Client-Id", client_id);
                        },
                        url: "https://api.twitch.tv/"+api+"/games?id="+gameId,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function(response) {
                            var liveGame = response.data[0]['name'];
                            liveGame = "Joue &#xE0; : " + liveGame
                            $('#gamePlaying').html(liveGame);   
                        }
                        });
                    //Stream is online



                }   


            }
          });
    }
```

if you want my final extension i open source it on github : https://github.com/aimericrouyer/twhitch-chrome-extention-for-kalevis-